# Dynamic Different Images Horizontal RecyclerView in Vertical RecyclerView like Google Play Store

Tags: java, android, nested, android-recyclerview

I have been following this tutorial:

http://android-pratap.blogspot.co.za/2015/12/horizontal-recyclerview-in-vertical.html

All the code is on the blog. What I am trying to implement differently is, instead of loading the same image over and over again, I want to pull 3 sets of images from 3 different `ArrayLists`. So far, I was using 1 `ArrayList` and instead of loading 18 images, the same 6 images are being loaded 3 times, so it's 3 duplicate sets of images, instead of unique images in all 3 rows.

**This is what I would like** (if possible from 3 arraylists):

> img0   img1   img2   img3   img4   img5
>
> img6   img7   img8   img9   img10  img11
>
> img12  img13  img14  img15  img16  img17

**This is what I am getting:**

> img0   img1   img2   img3   img4   img5
>
> img0   img1   img2   img3   img4   img5
>
> img0   img1   img2   img3   img4   img5

Here is the code I edited:

**DownloadImageTask.java**

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.InputStream;

public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;
    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urlDisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urlDisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

**SectionListDataAdapter.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.mypackage.appname.R;
import com.mypackage.appname.common.asyncTasks.DownloadImageTask;
import import com.mypackage.appname.common.models.SingleItemModel;

public class SectionListDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SectionListDataAdapter.SingleItemRowHolder> {

    private ArrayList<SingleItemModel> itemsList;
    private Context mContext;
    //Images Start
    ArrayList<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();
    //Download Images
    DownloadImageTask dit;
    //Images End

    public SectionListDataAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SingleItemModel> itemsList) {
        this.itemsList = itemsList;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public SingleItemRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_single_card, null);
        SingleItemRowHolder mh = new SingleItemRowHolder(v);
        return mh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SingleItemRowHolder holder, int i) {
        SingleItemModel singleItem = itemsList.get(i);
        holder.tvTitle.setText(singleItem.getName());
        urls.add("http:mywebsite.com/images/d"+i+".jpg");
        //Set Splash Images START
        if(holder.itemImage!=null){
            dit = new DownloadImageTask(holder.itemImage);
            Log.e("itemImage", String.valueOf(holder.itemImage));
            try{
                Log.e("imageUrls", urls.get(i));
                dit.execute(urls.get(i));
            }
            catch (NullPointerException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != itemsList ? itemsList.size() : 0);
    }
    public class SingleItemRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        protected TextView tvTitle;
        protected ImageView itemImage;
        public SingleItemRowHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            this.tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            this.itemImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemImage);
            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), tvTitle.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

RecyclerViewDataAdapter.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.pratap.gplaystore.R;
import com.pratap.gplaystore.models.SectionDataModel;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RecyclerViewDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewDataAdapter.ItemRowHolder> {

    private ArrayList<SectionDataModel> dataList;
    private Context mContext;

    public RecyclerViewDataAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SectionDataModel> dataList) {
        this.dataList = dataList;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ItemRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        ItemRowHolder mh = new ItemRowHolder(v);
        return mh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ItemRowHolder itemRowHolder, int i) {

        final String sectionName = dataList.get(i).getHeaderTitle();

        ArrayList singleSectionItems = dataList.get(i).getAllItemsInSection();

        itemRowHolder.itemTitle.setText(sectionName);

        SectionListDataAdapter itemListDataAdapter = new SectionListDataAdapter(mContext, singleSectionItems);

        itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setHasFixedSize(true);
        itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setAdapter(itemListDataAdapter);


        itemRowHolder.btnMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "click event on more, "+sectionName , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



            }
        });


       /* Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(feedItem.getImageURL())
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .centerCrop()
                .error(R.drawable.bg)
                .into(feedListRowHolder.thumbView);*/
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != dataList ? dataList.size() : 0);
    }

    public class ItemRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        protected TextView itemTitle;

        protected RecyclerView recycler_view_list;

        protected Button btnMore;



        public ItemRowHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            this.itemTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemTitle);
            this.recycler_view_list = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_list);
            this.btnMore= (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnMore);


        }

    }

}
```

SingleItemModel.java

```
public class SingleItemModel {


    private String name;
    private String url;
    private String description;


    public SingleItemModel() {
    }

    public SingleItemModel(String name, String url) {
        this.name = name;
        this.url = url;
    }


    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }


}
```

MainActivity.java

```js
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import com.pratap.gplaystore.adapters.RecyclerViewDataAdapter;
import com.pratap.gplaystore.models.SectionDataModel;
import com.pratap.gplaystore.models.SingleItemModel;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;


    ArrayList<SectionDataModel> allSampleData;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        allSampleData = new ArrayList<SectionDataModel>();

        if (toolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            toolbar.setTitle("G PlayStore");

        }


        createDummyData();


        RecyclerView my_recycler_view = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

        my_recycler_view.setHasFixedSize(true);

        RecyclerViewDataAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewDataAdapter(this, allSampleData);

        my_recycler_view.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

        my_recycler_view.setAdapter(adapter);


    }

    public void createDummyData() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {

            SectionDataModel dm = new SectionDataModel();

            dm.setHeaderTitle("Section " + i);

            ArrayList<SingleItemModel> singleItem = new ArrayList<SingleItemModel>();
            for (int j = 0; j <= 5; j++) {
                singleItem.add(new SingleItemModel("Item " + j, "URL " + j));
            }

            dm.setAllItemsInSection(singleItem);

            allSampleData.add(dm);

        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none" />


</LinearLayout>
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2dp">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnMore"
            android:text="Sample title"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnMore"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:theme="@style/MyButton"
            android:text="more"
            android:textColor="#FFF" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />


</LinearLayout>
```

list_single_card.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/itemImage"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/android" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/itemImage"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Sample title"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />


    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

In AndroidManifest.xml You would then need to add the following permissions:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Please help.

Comment: are those 3 RecyclerViews are different or Same?

Comment: @vrundpurohit They are 2 recyclers. The outer one is a vertical (RecyclerViewAdapter) recycler. The inner one, which I tried to edit is a horizontal recycler(SectionListAdapter). The code I posted is for the inner horizontal one. The code for the outer one is on the link I posted.

Comment: @vrundpurohit the 3 rows which are the output is supposed to be the same, as gven in the tutorial. What I am trying to do is to make them different.

Comment: @vrundpurohit please help

Comment: can you please show me your full code?

Comment: @vrundpurohit Hi I just added the rest of the code. Please help

Comment: you can add different array for different position inside `SectionListDataAdapter itemListDataAdapter = new SectionListDataAdapter(mContext, singleSectionItems);`

Comment: @vrundpurohit Thanks. Would you be able to post a working example of the code snippet you are referring to? I am so confused I don't know what to do. I'll gladly accept the answer and upvote

Comment: I don't have any working Example of that rn.. but I'll dig out and post in here if i'll find one.

Comment: @vrundpurohit Please do, thank you.

Comment: Did you ever get the answer to your question?I'm working on the same thing and facing the same issue