# Scrolling issue in horizontal recyclerview in a scrollview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gesture, android-scrollview, android-touch-event

I have a scroll view in my home page, inside that scroll view there are 2 layouts each layout for a recyclerview, each recyclerview will scroll horizontally. When I try to scroll the recyclerview the scroll of scrollview is getting intruppted and scrollview is started scrolling in vertical direction. So I tried the below code.

```
mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        int action = e.getAction();
        switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            rv.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            break;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }
});
```

Then I can control the horizontal scroll when I touch on the recyclerview, but now the problem is i cannot scroll my scrolview verticaly when I touch on the recyclerviews. Any suggestions pls.
My Exact need is I need scroll views and inside the scroll view few recyclerviews are there, it will work as like as google play store app.

[image]

This is my layout

```
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
    android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    sothree:umanoPanelHeight="368dp"
    sothree:umanoParallaxOffset="2dp"
    sothree:umanoOverlay="false"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    sothree:umanoFadeColor="#00000000"
    sothree:umanoDragView="@+id/dragView"
    sothree:umanoScrollableView="@+id/svScroll"
    sothree:umanoShadowHeight="0dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dragView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/menu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/svScroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                        android:id="@+id/vpImage"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:layout_height="170dp" />
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivDefaultAd"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="170dp"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:src="@drawable/default_ad"/>

                </FrameLayout>
                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/transparent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/space_1_5x"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/space_1_5x">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        >

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@color/white"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            >

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="25dp"
                                android:layout_height="25dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/space_2x"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_image"
                                android:tint="@color/blue"/>

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:padding="@dimen/space_2x"


                                android:textSize="@dimen/txt_x_medium" />

                            <TextView

                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:text="@string/more"
                                android:textColor="@color/more_orange"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/txt_medium"
                                tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />
                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="15dp"
                                android:layout_height="15dp"
                                android:tint="@color/more_orange"
                                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/space_2x"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_right_arrow_small"/>
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:background="@color/light_gray1" />

                        <FrameLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="150dp"
                            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                            android:focusable="true"
                            android:background="@color/white">
                            <com.wang.avi.AVLoadingIndicatorView
                                android:id="@+id/avi"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"

                                app:indicatorName="LineSpinFadeLoaderIndicator" />

                            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:background="@color/transparent"
                                android:orientation="horizontal" />
                            <LinearLayout

                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:background="@color/white"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:visibility="gone">

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="@string/txt_msg_no_data"
                                    android:textColor="@color/no_items_txt_color"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/txt_x_medium" />
                            </LinearLayout>
                        </FrameLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/transparent">

                    <LinearLayout

                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        >

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@color/white"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:tag="sticky">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="25dp"
                                android:layout_height="25dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/space_2x"

                                android:tint="@color/blue"
                                android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc"/>

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:padding="@dimen/space_2x"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/txt_x_medium" />

                            <TextView

                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:text="@string/more"
                                android:textColor="@color/more_orange"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/txt_medium"
                                tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />
                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="15dp"
                                android:layout_height="15dp"
                                android:tint="@color/more_orange"
                                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/space_2x"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_right_arrow_small"/>
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:background="@color/light_gray1" />

                        <FrameLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="150dp"
                            android:background="@color/white">
                            <com.wang.avi.AVLoadingIndicatorView
                                android:id="@+id/avLoader2"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"

                                app:indicatorName="LineSpinFadeLoaderIndicator" />

                            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:background="@color/transparent" />
                            <LinearLayout

                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:background="@color/white"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:visibility="gone">

                                <CanaroTextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="@string/txt_msg_no_data"
                                    android:textColor="@color/no_items_txt_color"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/txt_x_medium" />
                            </LinearLayout>

                        </FrameLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>


    </LinearLayout>
</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

Comment: Try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39870099/dynamic-different-images-horizontal-recyclerview-in-vertical-recyclerview-like-g

Comment: And also have a look into this http://android-pratap.blogspot.in/2015/12/horizontal-recyclerview-in-vertical.html

Answer (score 5):

you should use **NestedScrollView** insted of **scrollview**

> [**NestedScrollView**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html) is just like ScrollView, but it supports acting as both a nested scrolling parent and child on both new and old versions of Android. Nested scrolling is enabled by default.

read **[ScrollView vs NestedScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34773982/android-scrollview-vs-nestedscrollview)**

and don't forgot to make  your **Recycelrveiw** `setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);`

> **[setNestedScrollingEnabled(boolean enabled)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)**
>
> it Enable or disable nested scrolling for this view.

**code**

```
YourRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Comment: where should  I set this "YourRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);" on touch listener?

Comment: no @ranjith add `YourRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);` after you set layout manger to your recyclerviw means after binding

Comment: I have tried this, but my design is bit complicated like the whole scrollview is inside a sliding panel layout, and I need the first layout should stick at top when they reach the top, thats why i used sliding panel layout

Comment: @ranjith you should use NestedScrollView insted of scrollview

Comment: @ranjith can you share your layout

Comment: I have added the ayout

Comment: @ranjith use NestedScrollView instead of ScrollView than try

Answer (score 0):

You can use two recycler views(horizontal recycler view nested inside one parent vertical recycler view). It will be more effective and give smooth scrolling.