# Recycler View Horizontal Scroll with 2 columns

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

Here is I have I have tried so far

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager =
        new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
```

but It showed 2 rows instead of two columns.

How can I show two items with horizontal scroll with recycler view?

Comment: You want 2 column for each item of RecyclerView?

Comment: you  want recyclarview like play store . please try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39870099/dynamic-different-images-horizontal-recyclerview-in-vertical-recyclerview-like-g

Comment: yeah this is what I want but 2 columns only

Comment: @ChhornSoro Have you found the solution? I'm facing the same problem

Answer (score 18):

Alright here is a funda,

When you are using `GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL`, second parameter will be considered as number of rows

while, when you write `GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL` second parameter will be considered as number of columns

Also, this

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager =
        new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
```

supposed to be,

```
GridLayoutManager layoutManager =
            new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
```

in above code, 2 is considered as number of rows to be generated.

Comment: yeah the item show 2 column, but it doesn't scroll horizonal but it scroll vertically. Do you understand what I want?

Comment: Yeah, because you have declared layoutManager as `LinearLayoutManager`.

Comment: now I change it to GridLayoutManager already and set GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL. Now I can scroll my product left & right perfectly, but It showed one column with 2 rows. What I want is 1 row with 2 columns. Please help Thanks

Comment: Have you found the solution? I'm facing the same problem

Answer (score 7):

To achieve what you need you need to combine two things: setup GridLayoutManager and set up adapter:

in Fragment/Activity:

```
 val snapHelper = PagerSnapHelper()
        snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView)

//Grid layout, 2 columns
        recyclerView.layoutManager =
            GridLayoutManager(this.context, 2, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false)
```

and then in your adapter:

```
var displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
private var screenWidth = 0
```

in onCreateViewHolder:

```
(parent.context as MainActivity).windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(displayMetrics)
    screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels
```

in onBindViewHolder:

```
    val itemPadding = 8

    //here you may change the divide amount from 2.5 to whatever you need 
    val itemWidth = (screenWidth - itemPadding).div(2.5)

    val layoutParams = holder.itemView.layoutParams
    layoutParams.height = layoutParams.height
    layoutParams.width = itemWidth.toInt()
    holder.itemView.layoutParams = layoutParams
```

Comment: I faced the same problem and with this answer, I could resolve the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Recently faced the same problem, ended with creating a custom GridLayoutManager that allowed me to fix the row count and column count together.

Link : -https://gist.github.com/KaveriKR/04bfef5ffc9c00a8b6fca503da497322

This custom layout manger makes use of the `generateDefaultLayoutParams` and two other functions to set different layout params for the layout manger.

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

Answer (score 0):

All answers at Java but if someone searches for Kotlin;

```
val layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(requireContext(),  2)

    recyclerViewSymbol.layoutManager = symbolLayoutManager
```

Answer (score -3):

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(activity,2,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code only answers can generally be improved by adding some explanation of how and why they work. For older questions with existing answers it can also be useful to point out what new aspect of the question or improved technique your answer addresses.